# How can I add title like command?

Tags: beamer, macros, beamerposter

I am making a poster where I edited an existing style

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
    \vskip4.5cm
    \hskip14cm
    \mbox{% 
        \begin{minipage}[r][][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-15cm\relax}
            \begin{flushright}
                \usebeamercolor{title of headline}{\color{fg}{\inserttitle}}
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}%
    }% 
}
```

Calling the `inserttitle` it will insert the title which was set in the main text file via the `title` command. I would like to know how can be created a new commands which behaves the same way as the `title`.ex \insertuniversityadress.

```
\title{This is is a title}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "clone" the title macro adjusting it for your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter         
\newcommand{\universityaddress}{\@dblarg\beamer@universityaddress}  %this is where we are cloning the \title macro 
\long\def\beamer@universityaddress[#1]#2{%
  \def\insertuniversityaddress{#2}%
  \def\beamer@shortuniversityaddress{#1}%
  \def\insertshortuniversityaddress{#1}
  }
\makeatother


\title[Title]{this is a title}
\universityaddress[Un. Add.]{This is the university address}
\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}
  \insertshorttitle

  \inserttitle

  \insertshortuniversityaddress

  \insertuniversityaddress
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It behaves like the title macro (with an optional short version).